# How to combine these queries together as one result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(recipe_id) AS Found
FROM recipe_ingredients R, users_ingredients U
WHERE R.key_ingredient = U.key_ingredient;

SELECT recipe_id, COUNT(recipe_id) As Count FROM recipe_ingredients GROUP BY recipe_id;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and why can't you Google it?  Plenty of documentation on this.

Comment: I have tried everything, I have spent many hours googling it too... The problem is I want one column to show all ingredients and the other so show how many are matched from two table... I have been unable to display it as one result .. I have tried joining tables UNION all sorts.  I would really appreciate some help ASAP Thank you @LukePark

Comment: Is output columns are `recipe_id, recipeFound, recipeCount`? For each recipe you want to show the count and found ?

Comment: @Arulkumar Sorry please can you clarify what you mean..... There should be three column first recipe id second showing found ingredients and third  showing all ingredients for that recipe..... there are two tables one recipes_ingredients & two users_ingredients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments what I understand is you need to show three columns as `recipeId, foundIngredients, countIngredients`.

Since with out table schema I assumed the structure and derive the below query:

SQL Fiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eee151/3

```
SELECT COU.recipe_id, IFNULL(FOU.Found, 0) AS Found, COU.Count
FROM  ( SELECT recipe_id, COUNT(recipe_id) As Count 
        FROM recipe_ingredients 
        GROUP BY recipe_id) COU
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT R.recipe_id, COUNT(R.key_ingredient) AS Found
        FROM users_ingredients U
        JOIN recipe_ingredients R ON R.key_ingredient = U.key_ingredient
        GROUP BY R.recipe_id) FOU ON FOU.recipe_id = COU.recipe_id
```

Comment: Thank you Mate Perfect!... is it possible to calculate the difference between the found and count in this same query.. and JOIN a third table using recipe_ingredients recipe_id